# mysql join condition - restrict join to single row in group based on custom order

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Sorry for the poor title, but it's hard to explain in a single line.

I have a table of widget data - each record has an id, created timestamp,  device_id (external key), and a status ('prelim' or 'official'). I'm trying to get a single, newest, "most official" record for each device - this means I want the newest official record, but if there isn't an official one, the newest prelim one.  Example

```
ID | created | device_id | status   | data
1  | 100     | A         | prelim   | ##
2  | 105     | A         | prelim   | ##
3  | 107     | B         | official | ##
4  | 109     | B         | prelim   | ##
```

I should get row 2 because it's there is no official record, and it is the newest record for device A, and row 3 because it's the newest official record for device B (any prelim record after an official one should be ignored).

Currently, I'm using this query:

```
Select widget.* from widget
INNER JOIN (select id, device_id, status, max(created) as created from widget
        group by device_id, status) max_widget
    on widget.created = max_widget.created and widget.device_id = max_widget.device_id
```

This query gives me the newest rows grouped by device and status, so in the case of device B, it returns 2 rows - not what I need.

How did I restrict the join to return only the official row if it exists. I feel like I should be able to solve this with a where on the inner query, or a coalesce()in the join clause, but I can't quite wrap my brain around it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select *
from widget w
where id = (
        select id
        from widget x
        where w.device_id = x.device_id
        order by field(status, 'official', 'prelim'), created desc
        limit 1
        );
```

`order by field(status, 'official', 'prelim')` keeps "official" records first and `created desc` keeps latest ones first in that. `limit 1` fetches one row which we can use in the where clause.

Comment: I would be explicit about the status ordering (using, say, `order by field(status, 'official', 'prelim')`) but this is a good solution.

Comment: I tend to run far away from correlated subqueries due to some past performance issues... but this does solve the problem. Won't this require the subquery to be run for every single row in widget to check for a match?

Comment: @whiteatom . . . Actually, Gurwinders solution with an index on `widget(device_id, status, created, id)` should have good performance.

Comment: With the index, the performance hit is not noticeable - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
create table widget (
    id smallint, 
    created smallint, 
    device_id char(1), 
    status varchar(20),
    data varchar(20));

insert into widget (id, created, device_id, status, data) values (1,100,'A','prelim','abcd1234');
insert into widget (id, created, device_id, status, data) values (2,105,'A','prelim','efgh5678');
insert into widget (id, created, device_id, status, data) values (3,107,'B','official','ijkl9012');
insert into widget (id, created, device_id, status, data) values (4,109,'B','prelim','mnop3456');


select max(a.created), 
       a.device_id, 
       case 
          when b.id is null 
          then a.status 
          else b.status 
       end as status
from widget a
left join widget b 
   on a.device_id = b.device_id 
   and b.status = 'official'
where (
         (a.status = 'prelim' 
          and b.status is null) 
      or 
         (b.status = 'official' 
          and a.status <> 'prelim')
      )
group by a.device_id, 
         case 
          when b.id is null 
          then a.status 
          else b.status 
         end;
```

output:

```
+----------------+-----------+----------+
| max(a.created) | device_id | status   |
+----------------+-----------+----------+
|            105 | A         | prelim   |
|            107 | B         | official |
+----------------+-----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Not quite what I needed, I shouldn't get the record at row 100 - all I want is the newest one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to imply you could then aggregate the results - and this answer doesn't use any subqueries - let me amend the answer.